# how to fix Uncaught TypeError: Can't read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, null, typeerror, addeventlistener

in this question I want when I click the button with id="easy", the array is to be displayed in a 9X9 table its a sudoku initial structure plz help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Ruchika,
You have a button with an id 'easy'.You can simply get this button in your javascript code with the help of document.getElementById method,then store it in some variable and then apply the addEventListener to the variable .
Say you want to use a 'click' event on the button,you can do so easily like this:

```js
const btnEasy = document.getElementById('easy');
btnEasy.addEventListener('click',function(){
//your function code here
})
```